# Number of maximum degree vertices in a tree

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Let $T$ be a tree of order $n$, where $T$ has $\Delta(T) \geq 3$ leaves. Show that $T$ has exactly one vertex of maximum degree $\Delta(T)$.

I am stuck on how to prove this statement.

Answer (score 1):

let $T$ be the tree with vertex set $V$ and edge set $E$.

a basic property of trees is that $|E| = |V|- 1$. also, the sum over the degrees of all vertices is equal to $2|E|$, which implies: $$\frac{\sum_{u\in V}\deg(u)}{2}= |V|-1$$.

let $l$ be the amount of leaves which is also the maximum degree of the graph, let $c$ be a vertex of maximum degree $l$ we know exists. since the degree for leaves is $1$, and the degree of $c$ is $l$, we can extract them from the sum of degrees as $2l$:

$$ \frac{2l + \sum_{u\in V \setminus (L+c)}\deg(u)}{2}=|V|-1 $$
a bit of arrangement leads to:
$$ \frac{\sum_{u\in V \setminus (L+c)}\deg(u)}{2}=|V|-l-1 $$
since each $u\in V \setminus (L+c)$ is not a leaf, they all have degree at least 2, also note that $|\{u\in V \setminus (L+c)\}| = |V|-l-1$, so the only way for the equation to hold is if the degree of each $u\in V \setminus (L+c)$ is exactly $2$, implying there can only be a single vertex of maximum degree greater or equal to $3$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I understand your question.  What would it say about this tree graph?

[image]

Comment: Well, first of all, your example is a directed graph, not a graph. But if we ignore the edge orientations, it has $\Delta(T) = 5$, $5$ leaves, and only one vertex of degree $5$.

Comment: A directed graph is a graph.

Comment: By default, statements about graphs assume for the purposes of maximum degree that they're undirected. (But if you're willing to say that your directed graph has maximum degree 5, this doesn't matter.)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that there is 2 or more vertices of maximum degree $\Delta (T)$, then the number of leaves will be at least $\Delta (T) -2$, since (I'll consider it a directed graph now just to use the terms indegree and out degree, but it also works in ordinary graphs) every vertex in a tree has its indegree $1$ or $0$, so its out degree is at least $\Delta (T)-1$, and each edge coming OUT of this vertex is connected to at least $1$ leaf. (2 vertices can't be connected to the same leaf also).

Comment: Note that this is not a perfect mathematical proof, I just wrote the idea of the proof, you can be clearer when writing this proof and more "mathematical", but I'll leave this to you.